# Does Multiple URL Encoding result in different strings?

Tags: php, http, url, encoding

Suppose one URL encodes a string.

`urlencode(String1);` => Becomes `String2`

Does successive url encoding on `String2` create a string that is different from `String 2`?

meaning, `urlencode(String2) == String2` ?

`urlencode(String2) != String2` ?

Comment: Yes, if String1 contained characters that need encoding. Why not try out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly does create a different string, if the original string contained any non-alpha and non-`-_` character.

So, if the first `urlencode` encodes even one non-space, it will put a `%` in the resulting string as part of a `%XX` pattern. Subsequent `urlencode`s will re-encode that `%` (and start mangling your original string beyond recognition).

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/MQP7R).